AppwriteException: User (role: guests) missing scope (databases.write)]
Can anyone help me with this error of Appwrite. This happens when i am trying to run my project which will create the database and then the collection. I have tried all possible solution of giving roles to the project in the appwrite but still is not working. This is my code
I have tried all solution from the appwrite docs and also giving roles and permission to the project i have made in appwrite console.
import { db } from "../name";
import createAnswerCollection from "./answer.collection";
import createCommentCollection from "./comment.collection";
import createQuestionCollection from "./question.collection";
import createVoteCollection from "./vote.collection";

import { databases } from "./config";

export default async function getOrCreateDB(){
  try {
    await databases.get(db)
    console.log("Database connection")
  } catch (error) {
    try {
      await databases.create(db, db)
      console.log("database created")
      //create collections
      await Promise.all([
        createQuestionCollection(),
        createAnswerCollection(),
        createCommentCollection(),
        createVoteCollection(),

      ])
      console.log("Collection created")
      console.log("Database connected")
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error creating databases or collection", error)
    }
  }

  return databases
}

